# How can I refactor this js code to avoid eslint no-eval-func?

Tags: javascript, eval, eslint

I am writing a javascript code which calls an API and gets a javascript object as string. The problem is if I convert the string into JS code and use it, I get no-new-func ESLint warning.

Here is what I get from the server.

```
Line 58:  The Function constructor is eval  no-new-func
```

Here is the string I am getting from the API:

```
"[{'words': 'hello', start: 0.0, end: 0.0}, {'words': 'world', start: 0.0, end: 0.0}]"
```

It should be read as a simple array of object

```
[
  {
     words: 'hello', 
     start: 0.0,
     end: 0.0
  }, {
     words: 'world',
     start: 0.0, 
     end: 0.0
  }
]
```

Here is the code I used to convert the string as a javascript code:

```
const restructureChapter = (data) => {
  if(data) {
    if(data.length>0) 
      return data.map(chapter => {
        return {
          words: chapter.word,
          startTime: chapter.start,
          endTime: chapter.end
        }
      })
    else return []
  } else return []
}

const output = 'const tempText = ' + finalText
var fn = new Function(output + ';return tempText;')
var result = fn()
var outcome = restructureChapter(result)
```

Comment: The API is essentially broken. Fix *that* instead, so that it gives you proper JSON that you can parse

Comment: Can't you just use `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: If only there were some kind of standardised **J**ava**S**cript **o**bject **n**otation for tasks like this!

Comment: remove the other lines you only need `var outcome = restructureChapter(finalText)`, the lines above dont really do anything

Comment: @Akshay, JSON.parse() fixed it. Thanks.